# Checkstyle installation succeded but is not visible in Window => Preferences

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

I'm using Eclipse Galileo and I want to install Checkstyle plug in from http://eclipse-cs.sf.net/update and after intalling it using 'Install New Software' all seems OK and Checkstyle appears in installed software tab.
But in Window => Preferences it's not visible!!!

Note that the version installed of Checkstyle is 6.8.0

Can anyone help me please ?

Regards,

Comment: The release notes say Checkstyle requires Java 7, so are you running Eclipse with Java 7 (or 8)?

Comment: In fact, i am using jdk 6, is there any Checkstyle version which can match with jdk6

Comment: Look through the [release notes](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/#!/releasenotes) to find a suitable release. Eclipse Galileo is also very old.

Comment: Yeah it's very old and quite stable too :D, thank you so much for your answers.